# Adding an infinite loop into tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a program that involves including an infinite loop into tkinter. The purpose is to infinitely refresh the display with new data coming in. However as I know including a While loop before the mainloop will cause the program to freeze and after nothing will happen. How would I run the tkinter mainloop alongside another infinite loop so they work alongside?

I am expecting the mainloop to continue to run allowing user to interact and also the program to fresh the data presenting to the user. The loop must constantly update data.

This is my current main function which creates the app object and then runs the program followed by the tkinter mainloop. Example:

```
def main():
    app = Application()
    app.run()
    window.mainloop()
```

I then have this function which simulates data being updated by just repreadedly adding 50.

```
def update_test(Locations):
    for loc in range(len(test_data)):
        test_data[loc]['severity'] = test_data[loc]['severity'] + 50
        Location_Coords = update_severity2(Locations, test_data)
        for i in Location_Coords:
            print(i['fill'])
```

I need update_test() to run infinitely and simultaneously with tkinter mainloop

Comment: Use `.after()` to run schedule task to replace the while loop.

Comment: You can make a thread that has a reference to the component it needs to change

Comment: @acw1668. .after() seems to only run once?

Comment: @h4z3 I have tried the following:     Thread(target=update_test(Location_Coords)).start()
Thread(target=window.mainloop()).start()

Comment: @h4z3 however they do not run at the same time

Comment: You need to call `.after()` again inside the function scheduled by `.after()`.

Comment: @acw1668. So i have Update(data) and the tkinter mainloop(). Do you mean I need to call .after inside Update(data)?

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre], otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: @acw1668 mentioned "minimal reproducible example'. Your program is not executable, for many reasons ('Application' not defined, 'severity' not defined, 'import' not specified, etc)

Comment: How fast does this loop of yours need to run? Does it have to iterate over something thousands of times a second, or just a few times a second?